# Why is Z3 not able to solve this instance without a seemingly trivial modification?

Tags: z3, smt

The original problem is:

```
(declare-const a Real)
(declare-const b Bool)
(declare-const c Int)

(assert (distinct a 0.))

(assert (= b (distinct (* a a) 0.)))

(assert (= c (ite b 1 0)))

(assert (not (distinct c 0)))

(check-sat)
```

The result is unknown.

But the last two constraints, taken together, are equivalent to `(assert (= b false))`, and after performing this rewrite by hand

```
(declare-const a Real)
(declare-const b Bool)
(declare-const c Int)

(assert (distinct a 0.))

(assert (= b (distinct (* a a) 0.)))

(assert (= b false))

;(assert (= c (ite b 1 0)))

;(assert (not (distinct c 0)))

(check-sat)
```

Z3 is now able to solve this instance (it is unsat).

Why can Z3 solve the second instance but not the first one, even though the first instance can be simplified to the second?

**edit:**

While locating the problem I found something very strange.

Z3 solves the following instance and returns "unsat":

```
(declare-fun a() Real)
(declare-fun b() Bool)
(declare-fun c() Int)

(assert (distinct a 0.0))

(assert (= b (distinct (* a a) 0.0)))

(assert (= b false))

;(assert (= c 0))

(check-sat)
```

But if I uncomment `(assert (= c 0))`, the solver returns "unknown", even though `c=0` has nothing to do with the above assertions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that expressions like `(* a a)` are non-linear and Z3's default solver for non-linear problems gives up because it thinks it's too hard. Z3 does have another solver, but that one has very limited theory combination, i.e., you won't be able to use it for mixed Boolean, bit-vector, array, etc, problems, but only for arithmetic problems. It's easy to test by replacing the `(check-sat)` command with `(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)`.